# How can I read image files?

Tags: c, image, graphics

I need to get the RGB value reading image. How can i do it in C?

The image format can be png,jpg,bmp or other usual format.
It has to be saved in a text file.

Comment: OpenGL does not read or care about image file formats. You should [use an image loading library for that](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Libraries).

Comment: which language? which platform?

Comment: C programming language, saving in a text file.

Comment: Also remember that not all images use the RGB colorspace, and you may need to convert.

Comment: How can i know if that image is using RGB or other colorspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy-to-use image library that can cover the reading and writing of all these formats would be [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/).  It  is primarily a C library, but there are also wrappers for C++, etc.

When you say "saved in a text file", that is pretty atypical for images due to the fact that binary formats are much more compact that storing raw string values for the pixel intensities.  Additionally, many formats use compression, which would mean there isn't really a given "value" per-pixel ... instead the data must be decompressed before you can individually assign a value to every pixel.  There are some image formats such as [PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) that can be stored as ASCII data, but again, that's not necessarily the most efficient way to store a large image.

So for your workflow, you would use a library like [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) to read the values out of the image file, and then write back the uncompressed pixel values to a [PPM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) file, or a custom-formatted text file.